# Перенос Android проекта из Windows в Ubuntu

Tags: windows, android, ubuntu

Возникла проблема с переносом работающего под виндой андроид проекта на убунту 10.04 (запускаю на virtual box'е). Проект не работает вообще - эмулятор запускается, потом появляется сообщение предлагающее force close'нуть приложение. В чем дело не ясно

Comment: Вы делали экспорт в Windows, а потом импорт в Ubuntu ?

Comment: Вопрос звучит примерно как: *снял колеса одной машины и переставил на другую чет не пашет... В чем дело?* 

Дык мил человек - поясни: версию Android SDK, версию JDK (особливо отметь 64 или 32 бита, OpenJDK или сановская) - тогда чего-то можно говорить, а так Луна заслоняет Сатурн и внутреннее око ни фига не видит :(

Comment: Вы хотя бы указали, какой IDE используете. Потому что каждый IDE формирует проект по своему шаблону (пространно говорю), и это не только к Android относится.

Comment: @Barmaley у кого-то вы эту фразу сперли))    
@kraft_lawrence - свет мой, зеркальце, скажи, да всю правду доложи    
версию у SDK    
IDE и JDK...
А еще есть такая штука, как LogCat, в которой можно увидеть стактрейс, который укажет почему крашится приложение.